# UIScrollView Repositioning after return from a navigated View

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview

I am using a scroll view and by using a button in it, I navigate to a new view. The problem is when i pop (return) to my scroll view again from the new view, the scroll view seems repositioned to the top and I cannot see the controls I have added to the top half of the scroll view.
The frame size of my sroll view attached.

How can I fix this issue if any one come across the same?[image: My srllview frame sizes]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `setContentOffset:animated` to set scroll view position. Something like this:

```
[self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 180) animated:YES];
```

Comment: I cannot point to a exact offset value, you should try the values because you know which elements you need to display.

Comment: thanks amb [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:YES]; worked!!